# qtcreator Could not find 'share/std_msgs/cmake/std_msgs-msg-paths.cmake'

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

error info:
/opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:271: error: Could not find 'share/std_msgs/cmake/std_msgs-msg-paths.cmake' (searched in '/home/westeast/git/enmodel/devel'). trajectory/CMakeLists.txt:72 (generate_messages)

I add some .msg file in my package
but the qtcreator IDE can not build the msg .
I can build the package with msg in cmd by catkin_make

Is anyone know the reason?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261585/qtcreator-could-not-find-%27share/std_msgs/cmake/std_msgs-msg-paths.cmake%27/) by [westeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/30354/westeast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to me you are running into this problem: #q202401

Can you see if sourcing your environment has the desired effect? If not, please post your complete CMakeLists.txt and the output of `echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [westeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/30354/westeast/) on 2017-05-12**:
thanks so so much . I solve the problem by add CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/westeast/git/enmodel/devel;/opt/ros/indigo in my qt build config. At the begining my $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is empty.

and emember click the apply button when you change the config.